# PySpark's when-function not working as expected?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code (it is reduced to what is important for my question, so please don't be confused that the logic might not make that much sense):

```
def myFunction(x):
    if(x == 'A'):
        raise ValueError('x should not be A: ' + str(x == 'A'))
    return 0

myUdf= F.udf(lambda x: myFunction(x), IntegerType())

isA = F.col('string_col') == 'A'

df = df.withColumn('new_col',
                   F.when(isA, 1)
                   .otherwise(myUdf(F.col('string_col')))
```

What now happens is that I get the following error:
`ValueError: x should not be A: True`

That does not make sense to me, but maybe I misunderstand something regarding the `when`-function or how data is processed, but I thought the `when`-function is some kind of if-else and therefore if the column `string_col` contains an 'A' the part in `.otherwise()` should not be executed... but obviously it is. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the udf you declared the type of x as IntegerType() and then gave it string 'A'. Change IntegerType() to StringType().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: According to the documentation, PySparks function ``udf`` takes as a second argument the ``ReturnType`` of the function. It is not used to specify what type the input is from what I understood. Furthermore, this is not the error...